# show multiple select selected value only

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am trying to get multiple specific class select each selected value am not able to achieve it for example i have 3 select with class `Candidates_dd`  and i want the selected value of that specific class select selected separated  by coma`,`.

HTML

```
        <select class="Candidates_dd" id="Candidate_for_po_1">
            <option value="1">None of the mentioned candidates</option>
            <option value="AB4BB5">AB4BB5 - 1 1</option>
            <option value="C3B239">C3B239 - 2 2</option>
            <option value="E2A3D3">E2A3D3 - 33 3</option>
            <option value="HFDG35">HFDG35 - 4 4</option>
        </select>

        <select class="Candidates_dd" id="Candidate_for_po_2">
            <option value="2">None of the mentioned candidates</option>
            <option value="AB4BB5">AB4BB5 - 1 1</option>
            <option value="C3B239">C3B239 - 2 2</option>
            <option value="E2A3D3">E2A3D3 - 33 3</option>
            <option value="HFDG35">HFDG35 - 4 4</option>
        </select>

        <select class="Candidates_dd" id="Candidate_for_po_3">
            <option value="3">None of the mentioned candidates</option>
            <option value="AB4BB5">AB4BB5 - 1 1</option>
            <option value="C3B239">C3B239 - 2 2</option>
            <option value="E2A3D3">E2A3D3 - 33 3</option>
            <option value="HFDG35">HFDG35 - 4 4</option>
        </select>
```

JS

```
var selected_val = $.map($("select[class='Candidates_dd']:selected"), function(a)
    {
        return a.value;
    }).join(',');

alert(selected_val);
```

Comment: Try changing your initial selector in the map to `$("select.Candidates_dd").find(":selected")`

Answer (score 0):

It was so simple Finally solved the issue

[fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AqUN7/14/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var arr = [];
    $('.Candidates_dd option:selected').each(function () {
  arr.push($(this).val())
    });
      alert(arr.join(','));
})
```